# Flashing Hex File to AT89C51

Tags: atmel, 8051, max232, cp2102, hex-file

I have a USB to Serial breakout which has CP2102 and MAX232 chips on it. I wrote a program in Keil and generated the Hex File. How do I flash this hex file onto the AT89C51 (which is also another board with all the capacitors,resistors and crystal oscillator, everything is there) using the USB to Serial breakout? Flash Magic works only for philips chips, what is the alternative to ATmel chips?

[image: AT89C51 BREAKOUT]
[image: USB to SERIAL BREAKOUT]

Answer (score 1):

The AT89C51 chip should contain an embedded USB boot loader pre-loaded on the chip.  The boot loader is used to program the flash.  The USB Boot-loader is described in this document.

http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4287.pdf

The USB Boot-Loader works with the Atmel FLIP software.  The FLIP software is available for free from the Atmel website.

http://www.atmel.com/tools/FLIP.aspx

Comment: I've flashed an Arduino Bootloader before on an AVR chip, how is it done with this? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: same concept different software